# Cannot see VOIP calls in Wireshark 2.0.0

Tags: voip, wireshark, pcap

I received a pcap dump from a site who's VOIP traffic I need to analyse. I use Wireshark's VOIP calls analyser via the menu:

[image]

The conversations display fine in Wireshark v1.10.8, but when I upgraded to Wireshark **v2.0.0**, no conversations are shown for the same pcap file.

Is there a bug in WS 2.0.0? Or am I the bug? (as usual xD)

PS: I unfortunately cannot share the pcap file as it is sensitive client data.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It's not programming related. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I cant say about what happened with Wireshark 2.0.0, but if you want to work on voip traffic, then you can easily put basic filters like udp or SIP and applying src and destination ip filter to do your job.

Comment: would i still be able to playback the audio that way though?

Answer (score 0):

File a bug at [the Wireshark Bugzilla](http://bugs.wireshark.org), so that the Wireshark developers can determine whether this is a bug and ask for more details.